# Sencha Touch - Sometimes POST's, others does a GET request

Tags: javascript, post, sencha-touch

I'm using Sencha Touch 1.1, and having some issues with a form. When pressing submit when opened on another computer, the form is making a POST request, and everything is being processed correctly. On my computer whenever I open the page and submit the form, it's making a GET request (according to developer tools) and not posting any data.

Has anyone encountered a similar bug? Or any ideas where to look for what could cause such a thing? I'm absolutely baffled.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the 'GET' request when using Chrome, it seems the latest update changed something that caused this problem with Sencha. It can be solved by explicitly specifying the post method when submitting the form:

```
submit({
    method  : 'POST',
    waitMsg : {message:'Submitting', cls : 'demos-loading'}
});
```

You can find more info here:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?162294-Form-data-not-submitted-after-Chrom-update